# Based on value, show pass or fail

Tags: python, pandas, user-interface, tkinter

```
toc_ccv.insert(11, 'QC Result', '')
toc_ccv['Recovery (%)'] = toc_ccv['TOC (ppmC)']/ toc_ccv['Prepared Value (ppmC)'] * 100
toc_ccv['Abs Difference'] = abs(toc_ccv['TOC (ppmC)']-toc_ccv['Prepared Value (ppmC)'])
```

I would like to do a check on value of the above calculation. If the value of the Recovery % is within
90-110%, I want to show that it's Passing and if not, failing and put the statement (Pass or fail) under the QC Results column.

so for example below, the word "PASS" should be under QC Results column for both values since the recovery % is within the accepted range.

[image]

Comment: Could you include what you've tried and what doesn't work with that attempt?

Comment: I've tried and/if and I get errors. I know it's hard to put to words what I am trying to accomplish, But I'm doin a simple calculation and coverted to percent. Now if that percent is within 90-110, my results are passing, if not, they're failing.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the `&` of two conditions to get it to be `True`/`False` then map the `True`/`False` to be `Pass`/`Fail`.

```
df['QC Result'] = ((df['Recovery (%)'] >= 90) & (df['Recovery (%)'] <= 110)).replace({True: 'Pass', False: 'Fail'})
```

If we break it down a bit we can see how it is working:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'%':[94.33, 88.11, 111.93, 110.00, 90.00]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
#if print(df) get A below
df['result'] = ((df['%'] >= 90) & (df['%'] <= 110)).replace({True: 'Pass', False: 'Fail'})
#if print(df) get B below
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
#if print(df) get A below
df['result'] = (df['%'] >= 90) & (df['%'] <= 110)
#if print(df) get C below
pf_dict = {True: 'Pass', False: 'Fail'}
df['result']=df['result'].replace(pf_dict)
#if print(df) get B below

#PRINT A
        %
0   94.33
1   88.11
2  111.93
3  110.00
4   90.00
#PRINT B
        % result
0   94.33   Pass
1   88.11   Fail
2  111.93   Fail
3  110.00   Pass
4   90.00   Pass
#PRINT C    
        %  result
0   94.33    True
1   88.11   False
2  111.93   False
3  110.00    True
4   90.00    True
```

Comment: ah ok will do 